# Tool to monitor complete TCP request and response

Tags: tcp, performance-testing

I need to performance test an application [BRM remedy, ar user] that is using an TCP protocol. I don’t have much knowledge on TCP Protocol.

I tried with wireshark to analyze the requests, but it is showing TCP request with data checks [Assuming that my data is splitting into small chunks by TCP protocol implementation].

Can you please suggest me some good tool that can monitor TCP requests and responses [like HTTP fiddler for HTTP Protocol]?

I will be using Jmeter for the perf testing.

Comment: What do you mean by "it is showing TCP request with data checks"? It just shows all the network data.

Comment: I have sent an authentication request [which contain user and password], but wireshark didn't show any of that data.
I need plain text conversion so that, I can use the same in Jmeter.

Comment: It may not know how to decode that application protocol, you may need to write a decoder for it yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might be seeing packets in the TCP format , but you can docode your packet in wire share too. 
Open your capture in wireshark go to Analyze -> Decode As ->  and all request will will traslated accodingly.

If you want analyse a specific TCP stream or want to to which tcp stream a packet belong to , right click on packet and click "Follow tcp..." , you will be finding allthe packets belong that particular tcp stream.

It mostly work for me with above two functionality , hope same for you.